# call model from laravel 8 on view

Tags: php, laravel, view, model, call

i want to call my model function from my view.
I tried like this but it didn't work

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav" data-coreui="navigation" data-simplebar="">
    @php
        $role = App\Models\Web\Systems\Role;
        //     $r = $role->getApi(1);
        var_dump($role);
    @endphp </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the function static inside of the model. After that in the view use:

```
\App\Models\Web\Systems\Role::getApi(1);
```